# how can i minimize my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making a javascript function that gets certain stuff out an URL and calculates a value.
This function works well but I would like to have some feedback on how I can minimize this function with less code. It looks messy like this right now.

I would really appreciate some help.

Code:

```
getURL()
        {
            const myURL = this.blok.image;


                if (myURL != null)
                {
                    const split = myURL.split('/');

                    const array = split[5];

                    const split2 = array.split('x');

                    const height = split2[0];

                    const width  = split2[1];

                    const calc = width / height * 100;

                    alert(calc);
                }
                else {

                    return
                }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide url sample?

Comment: this is an example. //a.storyblok.com/f/53830/6015x3900/7cea8305a6/mohit-singh-312892-unsplash.jpg

Comment: not sure why that is messy.... You can combine some line and not use variables, but not going to make a difference.  Other option is to use a reg exp and not spilt to get the values.

Comment: because i'm using a variable for everything. i was wondering if there was a way without as many variables.

Comment: So do not use the variables.... `const calc = split2[0] / split2[1] * 100;` ??

Comment: `const split = myURL.split('/')[5].split('x'); const calc = split[0] / split[1] * 100;`

Comment: regex maybe? `var re = /\/(\d+)[x](\d+)\//g;` `var found = re.exec('//a.storyblok.com/f/53830/6015x3900/7cea8305a6/mohit-singh-312892-unsplash.jpg');` `var height = found[1]; var width = found[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of split, you can use a regular expression to get the two numbers. Than just run the calculation with the two capture groups.

```js
const path = "/foo/bar/30x100/world"
const nums = "/foo/bar/30x100/world".match(/(\d+)x(\d+)/)
const result = nums 
  ? Number(nums[1]) / Number(nums[2]) * 100
  : null
console.log(result)
```

You can improve yours by just not using so many variables

```
const split = myURL.split('/')[5].split('x');
const calc = Number(split[0]) / Number(split[1]) * 100;
console.log(calc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either puth those splits in one line and use destructuring assignment to get the `width` and `height` :

```
const [width, height] = myURL.split("/")[5].split("x");
```

Or use a RegEx :

```
const [width, height] = url.match(/\d+x\d+/)[0].split('x');
```

```js
const url = `//a.storyblok.com/f/53830/6015x3900/7cea8305a6/mohit-singh-312892-unsplash.jpg`;

function getURL(myURL) {
  if (url != null) {
    const [width, height] = myURL.split("/")[5].split("x");
    const calc = (width / height) * 100;
    return calc;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

const result = getURL(url);
console.log(result); 

/***********************/

const getUrl2 = url => {
  const [width, height] = url.match(/\d+x\d+/)[0].split('x')
  return (width / height) * 100;
}

const result2 = getUrl2(url);
console.log(result2)
```